# What is the best way to federate users from Azure AD to Keycloak?

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, ldap, keycloak, federated-identity

I haven't found a clear answer addressing this topic, which is surprising given that it seems like a common scenario. Can anyone provide some guidance or resources for setting up this type of user federation?

I have done some research and learned that Keycloak can accept Kerberos or LDAP user federation, but [this source](https://www.securew2.com/blog/use-azure-ad-ldap#:%7E:text=LDAP%20Is%20Not%20Compatible%20with,then%20connect%20LDAP%20to%20that.) claims that Azure AD does not support LDAP. Despite this, I haven't found a clear "best option" for this process. I'm hoping someone who has actually set up this type of federation can provide some guidance or resources to help me achieve this goal.